# What's the Regular Expression for searching a String for "%5B%7E%5D"?

Tags: java, regex

In Java, I want to see if a string contains the following:

```
String link = "%5B%7E%5D/assets.jpg";
if (link.contains("%5B%7E%5D"){
   System.out.println("Yes this contains: %5B%7E%5D");
}
```

What is the regular expression for searching if a string contains: %5B%7E%5D?

Comment: If you're searching for an exact `String` you don't need a regular expression. Regex abstracts meta-text to broaden your search based on your own criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're searching for an exact String you don't need a regular expression. Regex abstracts meta-text to broaden your search based on your own criteria.

However, you can use `Pattern.quote` for literal matches, and `Matcher.matches` for start-to-end matches, or `Matcher.find` to search iteratively within a given input `String`.

For instance:

```
String input = "%5B%7E%5D";
String link = "%5B%7E%5D/assets.jpg"; 
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(input));
System.out.println(p.matcher(input).matches());
System.out.println(p.matcher(input).find());
System.out.println(p.matcher(link).matches());
System.out.println(p.matcher(link).find());
```

**Output**

```
true
true
false
true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String Str = new String("%5B%7E%5D/assets.jpg");
    System.out.print("Return Value :" );
          System.out.println(Str.matches("(.*)%5B%7E%5D(.*)"));
```

This would return:

```
Return Value :true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (link.contains("%5B%7E%5D")) {
}
```

Or it might well be that the link gets decoded at the server, and then:

```
if (link.contains("[~]")) {
}
```

One can easily without thinking convert such strings as (depending on charset issues):

```
if (link.contains("\u005B\u007E\u005D")) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to match against any string like `%2A%4A%0E/something_else` ? If yes, you can try next:
    `String s = "%5B%7E%5D/assets.jpg";
    boolean b = s.matches("%..%..%.*");`